# Programming Neural Networks with Python?

Tags: python, models, neural-network, economics

I'm a College student (Economics) and I want to program some monetary models using Neural Networks. I want those models to be able to predict future values of some variables using economic data, but I really don't know how to "model" the program itself. Is there any good Python module for that? I mean, a module for NN and a module for economic analysis?

P.S.: I'm using Python 3.x, but I can switch to 2.7.x if needed...

Comment: I'm sure there is some lib out there somewhere, but I give you a word of warning: it would be good of you to understand NN (to the point that you could program it yourself), rather than relying on the "magic" of the solution given by a 3rd party library. This is especially true if you are attempting to publish a paper.

Answer (score 3):

There is also [PyBrain](http://www.pybrain.org/docs/index.html). I didn't work with any library yet, but had some time to investigate the documentation. It looks like PyBrains has the simplest interface, compared to the available feature set.

**EDIT**
I have now (Dec 2010) some practical experience with PyBrain and like it very much.

Answer (score 2):

I've played with ffnet a little. PS - It was a pain to install.

"Feed-forward neural network for python"
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ffnet/0.6

Answer (score 1):

For large neural networks, you might want to consider GPU-accelerated libraries. 
Our own library [CUV](http://www.ais.uni-bonn.de/deep_learning/doc/html/index.html) comes to mind, as well as for example [theano](http://www.deeplearning.net/software/theano/index.html). CUV has python bindings, theano actually generates C++/CUDA code.

Answer (score 0):

Google [yields](http://www.answermysearches.com/four-free-neural-network-libraries-for-python/195/) at least four different Python neural network implementations; in particular, `bpnn.py` looks good just for its simplicity.

Or were you looking for an explanation of neural networks?

Comment: That site is great! Just was I was looking for... Thank you guys! But there is a little (big) problem: the posts dates from 2006. Two of the links are not working ( the financial example: that was great, I suppose!) The other two: are they compatible with Python 2.7.x? (no way with 3.x!!!). I don't want to "translate" the entire libraries. Anyway, the link is very useful. Thanks!

Comment: Most 2.x libraries are forward compatible with later versions.  Python 2.6 is the most popular version by far; 3.x will take a while before the bulk of libraries support it (though some small simple old ones may never).

Answer (score 0):

pyfann, is fast and well documented: http://leenissen.dk/fann/wp/