# Neural network library for Python?

Tags: python, neural-network

Can anyone (preferably with actual experience of the recommended library), suggest a good ANN library for Python?

[Edit]
ideally, the library/framework supports more than the basic FF paradigm. I would like one that has (or allows you to build) other network types e.g. a SO network for example

Comment: I would like to answer, but I am quite unfamiliar with your terminology. What do you mean with ANN, FF and SO?

Comment: @jsalonen I guess ANN is Artificial Neural Network, FF is Feed-forward and SO is Stack Overflow.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programming Neural Networks with Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628990/programming-neural-networks-with-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at [pybrain](http://www.pybrain.org/docs/index.html).
It's the most complete and programmer-friendly that I've found.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need native Python library, considering using an established neural network library with Python bindings. For instance [FANN](http://leenissen.dk/fann/) (Fast Artificial Neural network Library) provides [such binding](http://leenissen.dk/fann/html/files2/installation-txt.html#Python_Bindings).

If you explicitly need a library written in Python, I would suggest checking out  [Orange](http://www.ailab.si/orange/). Orange is an open source data visualization and analysis platform that can be either used as a library or a full GUI. it does not readily support everything you might need, but potentially you will find modules suitable work neural networks, such as [Orange SNNS module](http://ax5.com/antonio/orangesnns/) (not sure about its stability though). If you need to write a module of your own, Orange is a good candidate for a platform since it provides you with some basic tools.

Comment: Orange SNNS module page you have linked to contains the following link for the module itself: http://ax5.com/antonio/antonio/orangesnns/orangeSNNS.py/file_view  Unfortunately, this link is dead (404 error). Any idea where can one find this file?

Comment: Try this: http://ax5.com/wp-content/uploads/orangeSNNS.py.txt

Answer (score 1):

Watch  [neurolab](http://code.google.com/p/neurolab/)! You may configure your networks. Easy API like Neural network toolbox from MATLAB.